# Is there a way to reduce the if-statements? Python

Tags: python-3.x

Im writing a code, at the beginning i need to establish the attributes of my class, but those depend on the value of sueldo, so i wrote some if-statements to do that. Is there some way i can reduce them?

```
class sueldobruto:

    def __init__(self, sueldo):
        self.sueldo = sueldo
        if 0.01 <= self.sueldo <= 19.03:
            self.limiteinferior = 0.01
            self.limitesuperior = 19.03
            self.cuotafija = 0
            self.porcentaje = 0.0192
        elif 19.04 <= self.sueldo <= 161.52:
            self.limiteinferior = 19.04
            self.limitesuperior = 161.52
            self.cuotafija = 0.37
            self.porcentaje = 0.064
        elif 161.53 <= self.sueldo <= 283.86:
            self.limiteinferior = 161.53
            self.limitesuperior = 283.86
            self.cuotafija = 9.48
            self.porcentaje = 0.1088
        elif 283.87 <= self.sueldo <= 329.97:
            self.limiteinferior = 283.87
            self.limitesuperior = 329.97
            self.cuotafija = 22.79
            self.porcentaje = 0.16
        elif 329.98 <= self.sueldo <= 395.06:
            self.limiteinferior = 329.98
            self.limitesuperior = 395.06
            self.cuotafija = 30.17
            self.porcentaje = 0.1792
        elif 395.07 <= self.sueldo <= 796.79:
            self.limiteinferior = 395.07
            self.limitesuperior = 796.79
            self.cuotafija = 41.84
            self.porcentaje = 0.2136
        elif 796.8 <= self.sueldo <= 1255.85:
            self.limiteinferior = 796.8
            self.limitesuperior = 1255.85
            self.cuotafija = 127.65
            self.porcentaje = 0.2352
```

Comment: one thing you can do using creating dictionary using range as key and value ans params

Comment: may i know how the cuotafija  and porcentaje were calculated

Comment: @aviboy2006 is right. Whenever you find yourself hard-coding a lot of repetitive code based on different data, that's a good opportunity to consider some type of array or list to store that data. You might even store it in a separate JSON file. That way, your code is focusing on the logic not the data.

Comment: As an aside, this may not be the best place for this type of question. If it gets closed—and it very well might—I'd recommend looking at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is specifically for evaluating existing code that otherwise works. Of course, they have their own rules, so you'll want to read them before posting to make sure you're positing a question that will provide useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of approach you can to reduce number of `if` :

```py
sample_array = {
    "0.01-19.03" : [{
              "limiteinferior" : 0.01,
              "limitesuperior" : 19.03,
              "cuotafija" : 0,
              "porcentaje" : 0.0192
            }
        ],
    
    "19.03-161.52" : [{
              "limiteinferior" : 19.03,
              "limitesuperior" : 161.52,
              "cuotafija" : 0.37,
              "porcentaje" : 0.064
            }
        ],
    "161.52-283.86" : [{
              "limiteinferior" : 161.52,
              "limitesuperior" : 283.86,
              "cuotafija" : 9.48,
              "porcentaje" : 0.1088
            }
        ]
}

finder = 18
limiteinferior = 0
limitesuperior = 0
cuotafija = 0
porcentaje = 0

for key, value in sample_array.items():
    split_range = key.split("-")
    #print(split_range)
    if float(split_range[0]) <=  finder and float(split_range[1]) >= finder:
        limiteinferior = sample_array.get(key)[0].get("limiteinferior")
        limitesuperior = sample_array.get(key)[0].get("limitesuperior")
        cuotafija = sample_array.get(key)[0].get("cuotafija")
        porcentaje = sample_array.get(key)[0].get("porcentaje")
        
print(limiteinferior)
print(limitesuperior)

print(cuotafija)
print(porcentaje)
```

This is one of approach which I tried.

Comment: Don’t forget to upvote and accept answer if this help you @AlbertoGonzalez

Answer (score 1):

i used this to reduce if statement complexity.
i just assigned **limiteinferior**, **limitesuperior** not assigned **cuotafija**, **porcentaje** because idon't know how they are realted to given value if you know you can just edit the code inside forloop

```
class sueldobruto:
    def __init__(self, sueldo):
        self.sueldo = sueldo
        list = [0.01, 19.03,161.52,283.86,329.97, 395.06, 796.79, 1255.85]

        if self.sueldo < 0.01:
            pass
        for x in list[1:]:
            if self.sueldo <= x:
                self.limiteinferior = list[list.index(x) - 1] + 0.01
                self.limitesuperior = x
```